# How can i integrate Imagemagick with Meteor/angular2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor, imagemagick

I am attempting to use Imagemagick to manipulate images that are uploaded by a user.I already install Imagemagick package with meteor npm install imagemagick. but what I need now is how i can import this package to use it in my Meteor project

this is my code

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import template from './tpl.dashboard.component.html';


@Component({
  selector: 'traitement_par_lot',
  template
})
export class TPLcomponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
    var features = Imagemagick.identify('assets/img/unkown-user.jpg');
    console.log(features);
    });
  }
```

for the moment I get error 'Cannot find name 'Imagemagick' '

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `Imagemagick` symbol without importing or declaring it first. You posted your code as a screenshot so I would need to use Photoshop to fix it which is obviously not worth the trouble. Suffice it to say that you need to import every module that you're going to use, no matter if it's `Imagemagick` or anything else. See those Meteor packages:

- https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/imagemagick
- https://atmospherejs.com/classcraft/imagemagick

And keep in mind that ImageMagick is something that actually works on the backend, not on the frontend. You can use frontend code to make it run on the backend and that's what you should be doing but you cannot use it on the frontend alone without passing any data between the frontend and backend. If you want to manipulate images just on the frontend then you need to use Canvas or some library that uses Canvas for that.

Comment: I understood now that i should use my code on the backend but the issue how can I import Imagemagick module I tried something like **import { Imagemagick } from 'Imagemagick';** but it's doesn't work and thank you